# Writing the Key of JSON with an enum

Tags: javascript, json

I was trying to extract strings with using an enum such as:

```
var INGREDIENT = { COFFEE: "coffee"}
```

and then later wanted to have a cost scale for the ingredients

```
var COST = { coffee: 1 }
```

but i wanted to extract coffee to use the string:  INGREDIENT.COFFEE like so:

```
var COST = {INGREDIENT.COFFEE: 1 };  //target
```

but it was showing an error that `.` is incorrect.

I was resorting to:

```
var COST= {};
COST[INGREDIENT.COFFEE] = 1;
```

Is there something i am doing, preventing me from doing it like my `//target`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ES2015 you can write

```
var COST = { [INGREDIENT.COFFEE]: 1 };
```

Older versions of JavaScript (still very much in common use) did not allow that, however, and the only choice was to use a separate assignment via the `[]` notation, as in the OP:

```
var COST= {};
COST[INGREDIENT.COFFEE] = 1;
```

If you don't like having it be two expressions, you can always exploit the magic of functions:

```
var COST = function() {
  var value = {};
  value[INGREDIENT.COFFEE] = 1;
  return value;
}();
```

That's pretty ugly of course, but it's good to know in case you really need to squeeze some object-building code into some context where you can only pass an expression.

Comment: Whats a good cross-browser solution then for those not running older versions of js?

Comment: @cale_b what the OP has in the "I was resorting to:" example: a separate assignment.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was thinking your answer would be comprehensive / clearer if you spelled that out for others that come and find this.

Comment: @Pointy so this would work in say:  Google Chromes JS console?

Comment: @Fallenreaper well yes, with the caveat that you're in a sort-of weird lexical scope in the browser console. You could use the anonymous function hack I added to the answer, perhaps.

Comment: @Pointy the function might not be the best route since this is going to have a bunch of INGREDIENTS, but it is sufficient.

Comment: @Fallenreaper sure, but unfortunately in pre-ES2015 code you don't have much of a choice. You can of course make the function as complicated as you need.